# Scilab function plotting

Tags: plot, scilab

I really need to build this graphic from code written in scilab. I know it's may seems easy, but I'm new to this I don't know tools to do this or just simply can't understand.

[image: graph]
Currently I have this code

```
clf();
// ..a macro:
deff('[y]=toto(x)','y=x.*x')
plot(1:100,toto)
```

Resulting in next:
[image]

I will be very thankful, if you help me with code or at least have any suggestions.

Comment: Is the `python` tag relevant here?

Comment: You need to figure out the function `y = f(x)` that allows you to calculate `y` from the given `x`. Why do you expect to get that output when your `y` values are either `-1` or `1`?

Comment: Scilab uses python, as I know

Comment: But your question is about plotting it using scilab, isn't it? Presumably scilab also uses Windows, but you wouldn't tag your question `windows`

Comment: I'm sorry, the code have no relation to main task, I just previously tried to remake that code to complete my task, but met problems doing this

Comment: Yes, i need the function y = f(x). But I want this jump on 1st picture, where at x=50 graph moves to x=(~13) and then continues to grow as it was. I struggle to implement it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
x1=linspace(0,.5,100);
x2=linspace(0.5,1,100);
y1=x1.^2;
y2=x2.^2-.5;
plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask further questions about Scilab !